# How to depend on a rust crate in a git repo's submodule?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to consume [the `warp_api-ffi` crate](https://hhanh00.github.io/zcash-sync/doc/warp_api_ffi/index.html) in my (otherwise empty at the moment) rust project.
Unfortunately that crate is not on crates.io for [reasons](https://github.com/hhanh00/zcash-sync/issues/13). What's more, [the crate only builds when it is cloned as a submodule](https://github.com/hhanh00/zcash-sync/issues/14) in a super-repo.
Fortunately the super-repo has [a root-level Cargo.toml file](https://github.com/hhanh00/zwallet/blob/95aec7b9449be499563e89cc9e943deef1c50dd4/Cargo.toml#L2) with this:

```
[workspace]
members = ["native/*"]
```

And [the crate I actually want](https://github.com/hhanh00/zcash-sync/blob/d91b60309b9b414ad5359ae3da4407b8abe234df/Cargo.toml#L30-L32) to access is brought in (via submodule) at `native/zcash-sync`.

I believe cargo is supposed to support this scenario. So in my own Cargo.toml I have this:

```ini
[dependencies]
"warp_api_ffi" = { git = "https://github.com/hhanh00/zwallet.git", features = ["dart_ffi"] }
```

But when I run `cargo check`, I see this failure:

> error: failed to get `warp_api_ffi` as a dependency of package
> `my-zcash-sync v0.1.0 (/home/andrew/git/my-zcash-sync)`
>
> Caused by:   failed to load source for dependency `warp_api_ffi`
>
> Caused by:   Unable to update https://github.com/hhanh00/zwallet.git
>
> Caused by:   Could not find Cargo.toml in
> `/home/andrew/.cargo/git/checkouts/zwallet-9089bfd46a576ff5/95aec7b`

This doesn't make sense to me because there *is* a `Cargo.toml` directly in the directory it allegedly cannot be found in, which *does* (as outlined above) point to the submodule which *is* also brought down, so I can find the crate I want where I expect it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see the `Cargo.toml`, but I don't see any mention of `warp_api_ffi` in there. Would you mind pointing out where exactly you see it?

Comment: Thanks for looking. It's in "the crate I actually want" link in the question.

Comment: I haven't seen this before, so I might have to pass on this question. I didn't even know that you could give libs a different name than the package.

Comment: Well, that might be a useful clue anyway. But when I try depending on `zcash-warpsync` instead (which is the name of the package), the error message is the same.